# iPhone App: Yelp Api integration problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, yelp

in My iPhone App I want to integrate Yelp API

for that I download Yelp example from GitHub

I tried to Add All library files ,both Frameworks for Yelp and Github into my project

but still I am not able to  reference the files which are in framework"s Header.

like:GHAsyncTestCase and it is giving message  can not find interface declaration "GHAsyncTestCase" superClass of AOuthTest

What could be wrong ?

please help me to integrate it and if possible explain me all required steps to integrate it into my project.

Thanks

Comment: are you using Yelp version 2 ?

Comment: Yes, I am using version 2 ios example

Comment: @Maulik If u find any solution please let me know

Comment: @Maulik did u find any solution???

Comment: what problem are you facing ?

Comment: Actually  I want to Integrate Yelp to new project but not able to referance headers from framework and in example project  in target -test -> AouthTest which retrives data from json but i am not clear how to implement that same thing in to my new project

Comment: did you added frame work properly ?

Comment: Yes I have added normally. Is there any special steps to add frameworks and library ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have do additional settin in xcode

YAJL Framework Installing in XCode 4 (iOS)

```
* In Build Phases, make sure its listed in Link Binary With Libraries, along with:
      o CoreGraphics.framework
      o Foundation.framework
      o UIKit.framework
* In Build Settings:
      o Under Framework Search Paths make sure the (parent) directory to YAJLiOS.framework is listed.
      o Under Other Linker Flags in your target, add -ObjC and -all_load
* Import with #import <YAJL/YAJL.h>.
```

**EDITED**

you can create custom class or write the below code in any class but i suggest you to create custom class as follows :

in .h file say `test.h`

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "OAuthConsumer.h"
#import <GHUnit/GHUnit.h>
#import <YAJL/YAJL.h>

@interface test : NSObject 
{
    NSMutableData *responseData;

    NSDictionary *JSON1 ;
}

- (NSMutableDictionary *) getData ;

@end
```

now in `test.m` file

```
#import "test.h"
#import "OAuthConsumer.h"

@implementation test

- (void)test:(NSString *)urlString
{       
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.yelp.com/v2/search?term=restaurants&location=new%20york"];
    OAConsumer *consumer = [[[OAConsumer alloc] initWithKey:@"yourKey" secret:@"yourKey"] autorelease];
    OAToken *token = [[[OAToken alloc] initWithKey:@"yourKey-" secret:@"yourKey-Bc"] autorelease];  

    id<OASignatureProviding, NSObject> provider = [[[OAHMAC_SHA1SignatureProvider alloc] init] autorelease];
    NSString *realm = nil;  

    OAMutableURLRequest *request = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:URL
                                                                   consumer:consumer
                                                                      token:token
                                                                      realm:realm
                                                          signatureProvider:provider];
    [request prepare];

    responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    //[self prepare];

    NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    //[self waitForStatus:kGHUnitWaitStatusSuccess timeout:10.0];

    //NSDictionary *JSON = [responseData yajl_JSON];    
    //GHTestLog(@"JSON: %@", [JSON yajl_JSONStringWithOptions:YAJLGenOptionsBeautify indentString:@"  "]);
    //NSLog(@"%@",[JSON valueForKey:@"region"]);

    [connection release];
    [request release];
}

- (void) setString
{
    //NSMutableString *JSON = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    //NSLog(@"JSON Data Parsing:--->%@",JSON);
    JSON1 = [responseData yajl_JSON];

    NSArray *arry = [JSON1 valueForKey:@"businesses"];

    for (int i = 0; i < [arry count]; i ++)
    {
        NSLog(@"Res Name : %@",[[arry objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"name"]);
    }
    NSDictionary *temp = [arry objectAtIndex:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [responseData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [responseData appendData:data];

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@, %@", [error localizedDescription], [error localizedFailureReason]);
    //[self notify:kGHUnitWaitStatusFailure forSelector:@selector(test)];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection 
{
    [self setString];
    //[self notify:kGHUnitWaitStatusSuccess forSelector:@selector(test)];
}

- (NSDictionary *) getData
{

    return JSON1 ;
}

- (void)tearDown 
{
    [responseData release];
    responseData = nil;
}

@end
```

I hope it help. Its working for me ....

Comment: GHUnit framework is for testing purpose , if u wish u can omit it

Comment: Actually i omitted the GHUnit frame work apps work but the response data is null I don"t know what is wrong  can I have ur skype Name or Phone number on my mail id smartprerak@gmail.com for more help